# In Excel ,When some text entered in Cell B1 then =ROW() function should fire in A1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want the function **=row()** to fire automatically in cell **A1** when some text is entered in cell **B1**.
Can this be achieved using IF statement in excel cell.
I want this to be done without using vba script.
please help.

Comment: If you want to do this without using vba script, why did you tag it with excel-vba?

Comment: Thought vba user's might have tried this without vba.:)

Comment: One tends to tag for what the question is about, not what it isn't about. Someone who is looking for a problem for a excel vba solution to something shouldn't be finding questions that preclude what they are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell `A1`

```
=IF(B1<>"",ROW(),"")
```

Comment: Thanks this works..I want to automate this ,say it want use same from cell A1 to A10 but i dont want to change cell number like B1,B2....B10 for all rows, instead single formula work for all rows from A1 to A10.

Comment: [Excel Basics #8: Cell References Relative & Absolute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmVMjQzseLA) check his channel, one of best.